# My Flutter app is opening and closing back

Tags: android, flutter, virtual-machine

I updated Flutter to the latest version. And Kotlin, Gradle.

[image]

I get an output like this. What is the problem? And pubspec.yaml. This can be more help for you.

```
name: NAME
description: DESC.

version: 2.5.0+20500

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.6.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  http: ^0.13.4
  flutter_swiper: ^1.1.6
  provider: ^6.0.2
  get_it: ^7.2.0
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.4
  flutter_html: ^3.0.0-alpha.2
  flutter_html_all: ^3.0.0-alpha.2
  flutter_html_iframe: ^3.0.0-alpha.2 
  url_launcher: ^6.0.20
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.13
  share: ^2.0.4
  intl: ^0.17.0-nullsafety.2
  location: ^4.3.0
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.1.1
  google_maps_flutter_platform_interface: ^2.1.5
  simple_animations: ^4.0.1
  pub_semver: ^2.1.0
  package_info: ^2.0.2
  launch_review: ^3.0.1
  onesignal_flutter: ^3.2.8
  firebase_core: ^1.10.0
  firebase_analytics: ^8.3.4
  firebase_auth: ^3.3.7
  firebase_database: ^9.0.6
  flutter_math_fork: ^0.6.1
  webdriver: ^3.0.0
  supercharged: ^2.1.1
  flutter_svg: ^1.0.3
  
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.2
  change_app_package_name: ^0.1.2

flutter_icons:
  android: true
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/icon/icon.png"
```

I get an output like this. What is the problem? And pubspec.yaml. This can be more help for you.

Answer (score 0):

**check "null-safety" checks dude.**

```
 environment:
    sdk:">=2.16.0 <3.0.0
```

"

Comment: I Did . but everything in project is crashed

Comment: Don't Worry sometime Happen like this

Comment: you need you run flutter downgrade

Comment: Updated img, can you check it?

Comment: yes!I Think so you need to create new Project and copy paste all of your code to new one

Comment: I am trying , if it works i will write here. I hope it work